# How to retrieve the data from array in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have populated an array using explode from a comma separated string variable. Now I need to access the data in the array.

**I used:**

```
print_r($values); // to see how the data was stored
//output
Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( 
         [0] => 1rv09is001 
         [1] => 07IS72 ) 
  [1] => Array ( 
         [0] => 1RV09IS064   
         [1] => 07IS72 ) 
)
```

**I tried:**

```
$a = count($values);
for($i;$i<$a;$i++){
$sql="UPDATE subject 
      SET attendance=attendance+1 
      WHERE usn=$values[$i][0] AND subCode=$values[$i][1]
     ";

echo "$sql";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

It isn't working.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use PDO or `mysqli_*` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Complex variable names (or arrays, for that matter) need to be enclosed in curly brackets when used inside of strings. Also, strings in MySQL need to be designated as such with quotes (single `'` or double `"`):

```
$a = count($values);
for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
    $sql = "UPDATE subject SET attendance=attendance+1 WHERE usn='{$values[$i][0]}'  AND subCode='{$values[$i][1]}'";
    echo "$sql";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Also, you need to initialize `$i` with a value when used in a for loop.

Comment: `$values[$i][0]` is a string, you need to put single quotes

Answer (score 0):

Update your SQL statement:

```
$sql = "UPDATE subject SET attendance = attendance+1 where usn='" . $values[$i][0] . "' and subCode='" . $values[$i][1] . "'";
```

As far as I can see $values contains String values, which need to be quoted in SQL. Furthermore it is helpful to escape `" . $variable . "` array accesses.

Tested it locally and it works.

Comment: i printed the $sql and it turned out UPDATE subject SET attendance=attendance+1 WHERE usn='Array[0]' AND subCode='Array[1]'

Comment: Try to put `echo mysql_error();` after your statement or submit the `$sql` manually to the database via PHPmyAdmin to get some error message.

Answer (score 0):

You should quote strings that goes into your sql (also you should escape them).
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/entering-queries.html

Comment: He shouldn't escape them, he should use _prepared statements_

Comment: Of course, but now he won't get the concept of binding variables/values. I think at first he should understand the basics.